# Should I Bake Hair before Rigging model?

Tags: rigging, particles, baking, hair, auto-rig-pro

I just finished modeling and styling my character and i want to rig it.

I'm wondering if I should bake the hair from the particles before rigging-- ran into this issue because every time i bind the rig to the mesh, it does this to the hair. If anyone knows what to do please let me know

EDIT: I realized after binding (using Auto-Rig Pro) it duplicates the "main" body mesh... any clue why?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the order of the modifiers? When you bind the mesh to the armature (rig) an *Armature* modifier is added. It must be the first (=on top) of the stack. The *Particles System* modifier must go after it. So the armature can deform the mesh and the hair is added then to the deformed mesh.

Comment: i just moved the armature modifier but it seems it's still the same way.. do i have to do anything after i move it or?

Comment: No, when the order is correct it should work. Does the rig work properly? Have you enabled Hair Dynamics? Have you checked the face orientation? It's hard to tell from the screenshot only. Maybe share the file?